# Towers of Hanoi with two auxilary rods

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, towers-of-hanoi

I came across this problem on one of the websites.

Requirement:

Need to propose the algorithm and caclulate the time complexity of Towers of Hanoi problem if two auxilary rods are given instead of one.

My Attempt:

Original Towers of Hanoi:

```
T(N)= T(N-1) // Moving N-1 disks from Source to Auxilary 
    + 1      // Moving Nth disk from Source to Destination  
    + T(N-1) // Moving N-1 disks from Auxilary to Destination

     T(N) = 2*T(N-1) + 1 

            = O(2 power N )   // exponential.
```

In the current problem since we have two auxialry rods

`

```
     T(N) =

          T(N/2)  // Moving top N/2 from Source to Aux1

          + T(N/2)  // Moving the remaining N/2 from Source to Destination using Aux2.

           + T(N/2)  // Moving N/2 from Aux1 to Destination.

                T(N) = 3*T(N/2) 
                =O( 3 power log N base 2 ) 
                = O( N power log 3 base 2 )  // less than quadartic.
```

But I am not very sure about this since I am not calculation time as T(N/2) for moving  top N/2 to Aux1 and also for moving botton N/2 from Source to Destination using Aux2.

Why I think it is incorrect is because in first case  while moving top (N/2) we can play with three rods :  Destiation,Aux1 & Aux2
 But while moving the bottom (N/2) we can play only with two rods  Destination,Aux2

So I think there should even better approach for this problem.

Comment: Your second `T(N/2)` isn't quite right, since you only have one auxiliary rod at that point. I haven't figured out what's optimal yet, but it's probably still exponential.

Comment: IIRC, tower of hanoi had a solution of O(2^n) in general, and not o(n^k)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#With_four_pegs_and_beyond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple memoized recursive function in Python that uses the [Frame–Stewart algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Frame.E2.80.93Stewart_algorithm) to find the minimum number of moves. According to the Wikipedia article linked above, this algorithm is proven to be optimal for 4 pegs and up to 30 disks, and it's believed to be optimal for all combinations of `n` disks and `r` pegs (but not proven to be so). Its possible my implementation could be optimized a bit, but it's fast enough for reasonable `n` and `r` values.

```
def hanoi(n, r, memo={}):    # deliberately using a mutable default argument here
    """Return the number of steps required to move n disks using a total of r pegs."""
    if n == 1:               # base case
        return 1
    if r <= 2:               # impossible cases
        return float("inf")
    if (n,r) not in memo:
        memo[n, r] = min(hanoi(k, r)*2 + hanoi(n-k, r-1)   # recursive calls
                         for k in range(1, n))
    return memo[n, r]
```

Answer (score 0):

Base case -

1. If there are no rings, then return.
2. If there is a single ring, directly transfer to destination.
3. Transfer n-2 to 2nd auxiliary tower.  **First recursion**
4. Transfer second largest ring to 1st auxiliary tower and then transfer largest ring to the destination tower. Then, transfer second largest ring destination tower. **The 3 print statements**
5. Transfer n-2 to destination tower. **Second Recursion**

The idea behind 4th step is that there is no faster approach to transfer stack of size 2 to destination, no matter the number of auxiliary towers.

```
// Number of rings, from tower, destination tower, 1st auxiliary tower and 2nd auxiliary tower.
void hanoi(int rings, int from, int to, int aux1, int aux2){
    if(rings==0)
        return;
    if(rings==1){
        cout<<from<<" to "<<to<<endl;ct++;
        return;
    }
    hanoi(rings-2, from, aux2, aux1, to);
    cout<<from<<" to "<<aux1<<endl;
    cout<<from<<" to "<<to<<endl;
    cout<<aux1<<" to "<<to<<endl;
    ct+=3;
    hanoi(rings-2,aux2, to, from, aux1);
}

int main(){
    int i,n,j,k,l,m;
    cin>>n;
    hanoi(n,0,1,2,3);
    cout<<ct<<endl;
}
```